# With Selenium/Python how do I get the page viewable text of a checked radio button (or checkbox)?

Tags: python, html, forms, selenium, radio-button

I have a form that I am processing where I need to get the text values of all checked radio buttons (one radio button checked per line item of course).

The HTML is like so (for a radio button that is checked):

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;margin-right:15px;display:inline-block;">
<input 
   type="radio" 
   name="question_id[927]"
   id="question_id[927]" 
   value="276" 
   class="noborder" 
   checked="">Blue
</div>
```

---

Even though the `checked=""` attribute value is empty, selenium/python will return correctly that it is checked by calling:  `is_checked = element.get_attribute('checked')`, so that works.

The other radio buttons in the line item, that are not checked, simply leave out the `checked=""` attribute.

---

I need to get the word `Blue` into a variable.

After experimenting with many things, I cannot seem to extract the text beside the radio button.

---

I am successfully finding the list of radio button 'Element's', iterating through those and successfully finding which one is checked, and now only need to get the text value of the radio button that is checked to store that value in a database.

`webdriver.get_attribute()` only works with items inside the `<input..>` tag.

The text I need to get is enclosed by a `<div>`, and all radio buttons in the list are enclosed by the same `<div>` text.

---

I need to do the same with a list of checkbox values, getting the text from each one that is checked, and the construction is the same, with the text just after the `<input...>` tag and just before the closing `</div>`

---

I have searched every selenium / python article I could find, and am given no clue as to how to get this text.

---

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone anywhere has a working code line/snippet that would work to get this.

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you want to get the `div` tag text from the parent of the current `input` tag, so try using the `parent` approach like the following:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@checked]//parent::div')
print(len(elems))
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```

Reference: [`XPath Axes`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)